# Select largest absolute value column pairs with headers per row

Tags: t-sql, columnsorting

I am using: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0

Here is my sample table (numbers fuzzed):

```
    CREATE TABLE most_recent_counts(
       State                      VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
      ,BuildDate                  DATE  NOT NULL
      ,Count_1725_Change          INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,Count_1725_Percent_Change  NUMERIC(20,2) NOT NULL
      ,Count_2635_Change          INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,Count_2635_Percent_Change  NUMERIC(20,2) NOT NULL
      ,Count_3645_Change          INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,Count_3645_Percent_Change  NUMERIC(20,2) NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT INTO most_recent_counts(State,BuildDate,Count_1725_Change,Count_1725_Percent_Change,Count_2635_Change,Count_2635_Percent_Change,Count_3645_Change,Count_3645_Percent_Change) VALUES ('AK','2018-06-05',1025,5.00,1700,2.50,2050,3.00);
    INSERT INTO most_recent_counts(State,BuildDate,Count_1725_Change,Count_1725_Percent_Change,Count_2635_Change,Count_2635_Percent_Change,Count_3645_Change,Count_3645_Percent_Change) VALUES ('AL','2018-06-02',15000,4.00,10400,2.00,6800,1.25);
    INSERT INTO most_recent_counts(State,BuildDate,Count_1725_Change,Count_1725_Percent_Change,Count_2635_Change,Count_2635_Percent_Change,Count_3645_Change,Count_3645_Percent_Change) VALUES ('AR','2018-06-07',2300,1.00,2700,1.00,1800,0.50);
    INSERT INTO most_recent_counts(State,BuildDate,Count_1725_Change,Count_1725_Percent_Change,Count_2635_Change,Count_2635_Percent_Change,Count_3645_Change,Count_3645_Percent_Change) VALUES ('AZ','2018-04-26',107000,5.50,45400,3.00,180000,16.00);
    INSERT INTO most_recent_counts(State,BuildDate,Count_1725_Change,Count_1725_Percent_Change,Count_2635_Change,Count_2635_Percent_Change,Count_3645_Change,Count_3645_Percent_Change) VALUES ('CA','2018-06-07',140000,6.00,550000,14.00,600000,18.00);
```

It should look something like this:

[image]

<del>IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HuG8.png</del>

In the real table, I have some 600ish such counts.

I would like to produce a table from this table, where for each state, I have the top ten (in magnitude) pairs of columns (i.e. The abs. change, and the percent change) (i.e. if in Alabama's row, there is a minus 10 million count in the sales to people in the 46-55 range, that should definitely be part of the result set, even if the rest of the columns are positive accruals in the thousands)

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: your case it not clear enough I you have to explain it more on your data sample columns